# How i can set animation of engine cylinders?

Tags: constraints

I mean several cylinders rise and fall. And the one that first moves up, he also moves down.

I made it with constraint "transformation" and one empty, but it only works when moving up, when it is time to going down they do it in reverse order.

Can somebody explain how to fix that with constraints ?

Sorry for my bad English language skills.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain what kind of behavior you want to see? I see cylinder moving up and then down. Is the gif there for reference and not yours?

Comment: that gif mine. but animation wrong. nearest cylinder moving up first, and must move down first,

Comment: To give advice on that we first need to know how you animated that. Could you edit your question and provide more details on how you setup those empties, and why reversing the animation order doesn't work?

Comment: if it possible i need a way with 1 empty and constraints

Comment: Please use the [edit] link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you are animating those cylinders. It would be easier to help you if you upload your file. Use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the resulting link as part of the question.